# php pdo_ibm call stored procedure return null

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, db2

Good day everyone!
I've got remote z/Os server with ibm db2 database, and mine *centOs 7.3* server with *php 7.1.8* and *apache 2.4*.

Selection from system tables in db2 gave me info, but when I call stored procedure - them returns only **NULL, NULL**, but in specification written that it must returns **INT** - errord code, and **VARCHAR(800)** - error description.

And if I call stored procedure from mine Windows db2 client - I got **0,0** and needed information.

```
    $sql = 'CALL procedures.name(1,1,'text',1,1,'2017-08-30','2017-08-31',?,?)';
    try {
        $con = new PDO("idb:all_the_connections_stuu",'user','pass',
           [
              PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO:ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
              PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
              PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => 0
           ]
        );
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $errorNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);    //also trying without PDO::params  
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $errorCode, PDO::PARAM_STR, 800); //and with |PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT
        $stmt->execute();        //return *TRUE*
        var_dump($errorNumber);  //return NULL
        var_dump($errorCode);    //return NULL
        var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); //returns Error
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        $stmt = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo ($e->getMessage());
    }
```

I don't have access to change or view store procedures code, only execution.

It seems that when calling from PHP procedure is working - (when I set input parameters not 1 day, but year - it works about in minute before returns **NULL,NULL**).

And some of this procedures must create temporary tables, but they are empty.

Maybe PHP close cursor and loose all data? Or maybe something wrong with PHP PDO autocommit? Just guessing

__UPD:
Forgot about connection and statement erros, it's none.

```
$con->errorInfo();
$stmt->errorInfo();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => NULL
    [2] => NULL
)
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 0
    [2] => ((null)[0] at (null):0)
)
```

___UPD2:
Just forgot to add `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

```
    Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[57017]: <<Unknown error>>: -332 
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0332N  
Character conversion from the source code page "" to the target code page "" is not supported.  
SQLSTATE=57017
     (SQLFetchScroll[-332] at /home/user/shared/PDO_IBM-1.3.4/ibm_statement.c:1306) in /var/www/html/server/testsIBM/index.php:80
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/server/testsIBM/index.php(80): PDOStatement->fetchAll(7, 0)
    #1 {main}
      thrown in /var/www/html/server/testsIBM/index.php on line 80
```

Ok, probably I need new question for this error, but it seems that mine CentOs lang locale (because I don't install db2 client on CentOs) don't match to DB2 Server *DB2CODEPAGE*.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about your ibm db2 system, but I do know PDO. I noticed you only say in a comment what `execute()` results in, but you don't handle errors. See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, yes, indeed, forgot to add in question that info. Question updated

Comment: I don't see any updates, ah, now I do. Nevertheless, what I am trying to say is that you need to implement proper error handling. I don't see that. Errors can occur in many placed, check all of them with the appropriate code, always, even in production. In other words: The code in your question is incomplete, and you will never be able to answer with any certainty what is going wrong.

Comment: In addition to error checking the connect, prepare, bind, and execute actions, if you still get no data, I suggest you verify that the same userid/password can run the stored-procedure outside successfully of PHP, e.g from SQL (Data Studio or similar tool) or other scripting language when using the same remote database.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, of course I have try/catch in production, but in question I just wrote code fast suggesting that none of Exception was catched and all code working to the end. 
The code access to DB, and CALLing stored procedure, that a fact. PDOStatement::execute returns **TRUE**, so problem coming somewhere after, where my knowledge is ending...

Comment: @mao, yes, Windows client with same credentials to db2 server returns all information from same stored procedure.

Comment: I don't know PDO, but If the sproc returns a result-set, where is your fetch loop (or fetchall) to consume that result-set ?

Comment: @mao, omg, forgot ><  thank you
btw, you know how too set DB2CODEPAGE on CentOs without any db2_client installed? I just put *ibm_data_server_driver_for_odbc_cli.tar.gz* in */opt/ibm/* for PHP drivers can be compilated. Maybe some config can be created with DB2CODEPAGE=%server_code_page% ?
Or I need to install Full v11.1.2fp2_linuxx64_client ?

Comment: please don't mix different symptoms or different questions in one comment-thread, please open a new question instead and I will respond there.  Meanwhile did you add code to consume the result set, and is that working, because if so I can add that as the answer and you can mark this question as answered.

Comment: @mao, I still can't get needed info, cause of *error of character conversion*. Pls see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000415/php-pdo-connected-to-db2-different-codepage