# php pdo connected to DB2 different CODEPAGE

Tags: php, pdo, db2

I'm connecting to DB2 DB

```
$sql = 'CALL procedures.name(1,1,'text',1,1,'2017-08-30','2017-08-31',?,?)';
    try {
        $con = new PDO("idb:all_the_connections_stuu",'user','pass',
           [
              PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO:ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
              PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
              PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => 0
           ]
        );
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $errorNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);    //also trying without PDO::params  
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $errorCode, PDO::PARAM_STR, 800); //and with |PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT
        $stmt->execute();        //return *TRUE*
        var_dump($errorNumber);  //return NULL
        var_dump($errorCode);    //return NULL
        var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); //returns Error
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        $stmt = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo ($e->getMessage());
    }
```

and got this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[57017]: <<Unknown error>>: -332 
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0332N  
Character conversion from the source code page "" to the target code page "" is not supported.  
SQLSTATE=57017
     (SQLFetchScroll[-332] at /home/user/shared/PDO_IBM-1.3.4/ibm_statement.c:1306) in /var/www/html/server/testsIBM/index.php:80
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/server/testsIBM/index.php(80): PDOStatement->fetchAll(7, 0)
    #1 {main}
      thrown in /var/www/html/server/testsIBM/index.php on line 80
```

If I connect with db2_connect

```
$con = db2_connect("DATABASE=DB2D;HOSTNAME=10.243.13.65;PORT=5000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;USERNAME=asdf23;PASSWORD=asdfasf1","", "")
```

and output `db2_client_info($con)` and `db2_server_info($con)` I see that *CONN_CODEPAGE* from client = 819 and *DB_CODEPAGE* from server = 1208.

How can I set *CONN_CODEPAGE* in my client? I already set LANG in CentOs locale, but still got error of character conversion.

______upd:

Current $LANG = en_US.utf8 (also in *locale -a* I have en_US, en_US.iso88591, en_US.iso885915, en_US.utf8)

No matter what $LANG is set output from *db2_client_info($con)* still the same:

```
 ["APPL_CODEPAGE"]=>
  int(819)
  ["CONN_CODEPAGE"]=>
  int(819)
```

And same error about **Character conversion from the source code page**

I'm using PHP+Apache. Apache httpd.conf **defaultCharset** setting different locales didnt't change anything.

In php code **setlocale** don't changing anything either.

I think this setting store somewhere else, and **ibm_db2** or **pdo_ibm** drivers use it. =|

____upd2

The only way I found out - change DB2CODEPAGE from installed db2 client. But I don't have installed client. I'm using inly libraries.

Now i installed v11.1.2fp2_linuxx64_client.tar.gz (1.03 GB). But i can't laucn db2 client. Think I need another new question =\

____upd3

After all manipulations with CentOs, apache locales - I still get -322 exception. No matter what I changed - *db2_client_info($con)* still shows me 819 CodePage. And all work nice, until `fetch()/fetchAll()`

CentOs 7.3, PHP 7.1.8 with PDO_IBM 1.3.4-patched, and ibm_db2. **BUT** I make this modules from PECL sources (cause server doesn't have internet connection).

And I also don't have any DB2 products installed on mine application server (thats why I decide that CodePage getting from CentOs locale). It seems from your test, that `DB2 data server client` is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "IBM DB2 Data server driver for ODBC and CLI"  specifically for your Centos client, you can try ensuring that the environment for the account that runs PDO and connects to DB2 has DB2CODEPAGE=1208.  You can export this variable (only for this specific client type) via:

```
export DB2CODEPAGE=1208
```

and restart whatever process(es) are involved in your solution.

Also for the account(s) you are using to connect to DB2, their client LANG setting should be an UTF-8 locale (and that locale needs to be installed on your Centos). Use the command `locale -a` to show which locales are installed, and choose one which has an utf-8 for your territory. For example if your $LANG was en_us then change it to en_us.utf-8, if that locale is installed. Export that $LANG in the shell startup of the relevant accounts and restart your apps.

If you are using a full-DB2 client (or the local DB2-client on a DB2-server on unix) you also need to correctly set the LANG variable to a value compatible with the encoding of your DB2 database. Otherwise you will either get codepage conversion at run time, which may have unexpected results, including exceptions if no suitable conversion exists.

For information:

Tested PHP 7.0.20 with PDO_IBM 1.3.4-patched, and ibm_db2 , with DB2 V11.1.2.2 , on ubuntu 16.04 LTS - appl_codepage = conn_codepage = db_codepage.

Also tested PHP 5.3.3 with PDO_IBM 1.3.4-patched, and ibm_db2, with DB2 V10.5.0.7, on RHEL 6.9:  appl_codepage = conn_codepage = db_codepage.

Also tested PHP 5.4.16 with PDO_IBM 1.3.4-patched and ibm_db2, with DB2 V11.1.2.2 data server client , on CENTOS 7.3: appl_codepage = conn_codepage = db_codepage.

Note: Ubuntu , RHEL, Centos had default locale set for utf-8, before building pdo_ibm from github, or installing ibm_db2 with pecl. All local and remote databases had utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Done this already, didn't help. Error is the same. *CONN_CODEPAGE* still the same..

Comment: interesting thing. No matter that LANG setting in locale - *db2_client_info($con)* still show me CODEPAGE = 819.
So this code pages setting somewhere else, maybe in some other settings...

Comment: You need to be certain that the environment of whatever processes are involved in Php/DB2 picks up the new value of the $LANG.  Please show also your new $LANG value, and update the question to show the exact version of the DB2 driver for ODBC and CLI.

Comment: Which account runs Apache service(s) and PHP/PDO service(s)? If you su to these account(s) and show  $LANG, is the value "en_US.utf8" ?   Did you restart those services after changing LANG to en_US.utf8 ?

Comment: All running on the same user, and that user $LANG changing still got me nothing in output. Yes, services was restarted.

Comment: "got me nothing in output" is confusing . Do you still get the -332 exception?  If not, please consume the result set to get output. If you still get the exception, which action (connect, execute, fetch/fetchAll) triggers it, and please update the question to show the version of the DB2 data server driver for ODBC and CLI.

Comment: yes, I still get -322 exception. Question updated. _Sorry for long offline. Vacation)_

Comment: I can't recreate your symptom, per my updated answer. In such cases comparison of a working environment vs failing environment normally yields results.   To compile from source the PDO_IBM-1.3.4-patched , requires a full DB2-client (it needs the INCLUDE and LIB directories to be populated under sqllib).

Comment: oh, ok. Mine pdo_ibm.so maked from sources allows me connect to z/OS DB2 and retrieve data from system tables (_sysibm.sysroutines_ for example), but not call procedure with fetch ><.
Can you point me to download link for full centOs x64 db2 client?

Comment: is that it? 
`https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~Information%20Management&product=ibm/Information+Management/DB2&release=11.1.*&platform=Linux+64-bit,x86_64&function=fixId&fixids=DB2-111-linuxx64-RECOMMENDED&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http`

Comment: Use Google. Or https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24043794

Answer (score 1):

You may find, trying the tips described [here (with more explanations)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00332n.html) very useful, notably :

> Make the source and target code pages compatible with each other.
> Search the [DB2 information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9)
> using the phrase
> "Code set Territory code" for compatibility of the supported DB2 code
> pages. To set the client's code page compatible with the database code
> page:
>
> On Unix platforms, set the LANG, LC_CTYPE or LC_ALL environment
> variable to a locale whose code page is compatible with the database
> code page. Consult the platform documentation to see the valid locale
> names and the code page associated with each of them.
>
> On Windows
> platforms, set the DB2CODEPAGE registry variable to override the
> client's code page with a value compatible with the database code
> page.
>
> For database manager code page support, search the
> [DB2 information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9)
> using the phrase
> "Code set Territory code". For federated system users, see the
> Federated Systems Guide for data source code page. If the source and
> target code pages are compatible, then DB2 currently does not support
> this particular code page conversion. Contact your technical service
> representative to determine if such support can be added.